# Services similar to memcache

Tags: php, mysql, memcached

Memcache is great, but hostings don't support it (unless you have VPS). So, is there any similar services I could use instead of memcache?

MySQL queries cached in files, but for my app it's not very good solution, what else could I use? Thanks.

Comment: Are you open to switching hosts to something like Webfaction (not a VPS provider)?

Comment: @Interrobang: Thanks, will check that hosting. Are they quite fast everywhere? What about uptime?

Comment: I'm sure there are plenty of similar services, but I wanted the same thing you did (to run Memcached but not have to use a VPS) and it's been superb. They have servers in Texas (US) or also in the EU so you can pick which works better for you.

Comment: @Interrobang: So, in your experience they have good uptime? And are they fast, in your opinion? Is 256mb memory enough for new website? I want http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php not memcached, is it still ok? Or I will be able to download it through ssh?

Comment: This is kind of off your question topic. I've created a chat room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6098/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-8621637-services-similar-to-memcache

Answer (score -1):

all memcached is, from what i perceived is like a text file. so you can either try storing your objects/data into a textfile and retreive/store when you want or use mysql to do the same. also look at: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=memcached%20alternative)

Comment: No. Memcached is, as its name suggests, an in-memory cache. It is far faster than a filesystem cache.

Comment: The whole point of memcached is that it is faster than MySQL or filesystem. It's also not persistent, so it's not in any way like a textfile or a database.

Comment: i know it is a in-memory cache but an alternative and simple way would be to use a text file, it would be harder, and i dont know about speed, but it would work.